# Trying to generate id Field dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate an id field dynamically for each of the image which is uploaded dynamically. I'm not getting any idea how to achieve it. Given below is jquery code .Any idea for this issue would be appreciated.

code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>        
 input[type="file"] {

 display:block;
}
.imageThumb {
 max-height: 75px;
 border: 2px solid;
 margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
 padding: 1px;
 }
     </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Find the bellow HTML code
        <h2>preview multiple images before upload using jQuery</h2>
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                    var files = e.target.files,
                    filesLength = files.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength ; i++) {
                        var f = files[i]
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
                            var file = e.target;
                            $("<img></img>", {
                                class: "imageThumb",
                                src: e.target.result,
                                title: file.name
                            }).insertAfter("#files");
                        });
                        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                    }
                });
            } else { alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API") }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: id field means what? your getting a file from file input and displayed in img tag

Comment: why you ask here instead of in this blog http://www.splessons.com/jquery-upload-multiple-images-with-preview/

Comment: @KalaiselvanA through above code we  can upload diffferent images and i want to generate id field also for each of those images. i am not getting any idea how to do that.

Comment: what is the  purpose of the id field

Comment: @plonknimbuzz i think this is right place to ask.

Comment: @KalaiselvanA to use it for saving in database and perform any action on individual image

Comment: directly you can post it to your serverside code right

Comment: I think you want it to upload multiple image concept

Comment: @KalaiselvanA yes i want to save it and also retrive it and display on client side later when i want.

Comment: you can go with appendgrid

Comment: @KalaiselvanA how any idea since i am new to jquery so idea will be helpful.

Comment: go through this https://appendgrid.apphb.com/Demo or you can manually create a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an id dynamically by keeping some static id component, and appending a dynamic component to it every time a new image is created.

A crude example could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var idStatic = 'Image_'; //Static component of ID
        var imgCount = 0;  // Dynamic component of ID, will be incremented and appended to idStatic for each new image.


        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                var files = e.target.files,
                filesLength = files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength ; i++) {
                    var f = files[i]
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
                        var file = e.target;

                        imgCount++; // Increment dynamic part, so that id is unique.

                        $("<img></img>", {
                            "class": "imageThumb",
                            src: e.target.result,

                            id: (idStatic + imgCount),  // tell jquery to add the id for new element.
                            name: 'images[]', // give a name, so that server recognises it on form submit. Can be same as id.

                            title: file.name,

                        }).insertAfter("#files");
                    });
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            });
        } else { alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API") }
    });
</script>
```

That said, unless you are expecting modifications to the images on client side after they are added, you probably do not need the id. An additional name attribute should suffice.